# Boto3: A Future or coroutine is required

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, python-asyncio

I am trying to download 2 files from S3, using boto3, and wait until 2 files are downloaded, will continue to process 2 files

What I have done

```
async def download_files():
    await client.download_file(const.bucket_name, 'file/name.txt', '/tmp/name.txt')
    print('file 1 downloaded')
    await client.download_file(const.bucket_name, 'file/class.txt', '/tmp/class.txt')
    print('file 2 downloaded')
    return True

def main():
    ...
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(download_files())
    loop.close()
    ...
main()
```

I received an error

```
A Future or coroutine is required
```

It's first time that I am using `asyncio`, please advise me.

Answer (score 4):

boto3 isn't asyncio-aware... its functions are blocking, rather than being awaitable. So, the absolute minimum to do here would be to just remove `await` from the calls to `download_file`, and it should work.

```
client.download_file(const.bucket_name, 'file/name.txt', '/tmp/name.txt')
print('file 1 downloaded')
client.download_file(const.bucket_name, 'file/class.txt', '/tmp/class.txt')
print('file 2 downloaded')
return True
```

However, this would have poor concurrency properties if there were to be any other concurrent tasks in the thread's event loop: they would be blocked and wouldn't proceed during the downloads [this would make the usage of asyncio a bit unnecessary... concurrent tasks proceeding is sort of the point of asyncio...]

To have better concurrency properties, you should be able to call the functions via [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), which by default will run the passed function in another thread.

```
async def download_files(loop):
  await loop.run_in_executor(None, client.download_file, const.bucket_name, 'file/name.txt', '/tmp/name.txt')
  print('file 1 downloaded')
  await loop.run_in_executor(None, client.download_file, const.bucket_name, 'file/class.txt', '/tmp/class.txt')
  print('file 2 downloaded')
  return True
```

Alternatively, rather than using boto3 and threads, you could use [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and [roll-your-own AWS authentication](https://charemza.name/blog/posts/aws/python/you-might-not-need-boto-3/) (full disclosure: the post on rolling-your-own AWS authentication was written by me)

Answer (score 1):

look into [aioboto3](https://github.com/terrycain/aioboto3).  Also for more low-level look into [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore).  Both available via pip