# Concurrent Futures vs Asyncio Difference

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I trying to optimize a Python code by doing it asynchronous. For doing it I tried asyncio and concurrent.futures libraries.

Here are my codes:

```
async def get_rds_instances(session, region, engine_types):
    report_rds = []
    mandatory_tags = {'Use-Case'}

    client = session.client('rds', region_name=region)
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            response = client.describe_db_instances()
            rds_report.append(response)
        except (ClientError, Exception) as e:
            print(e)
    return reportd_rds

async def main():
... some arguments definition
    session = get_rds_session(profile_name)
    regions = session.get_available_regions('rds')
    try:
        reports = await asyncio.gather(*[get_rds_instances(session=session, region=region, engine_types=engine_types) for region in regions])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    
    ... process report

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Without asyncio this code completed in ~22 seconds. With asyncio it completed in ~20 seconds.

Yet, here the things getting interesting, I used concurrent.futures:

```
def get_rds_instances(session, region, engine_types):
    report_rds = []
    mandatory_tags = {'Use-Case'}

    client = session.client('rds', region_name=region)
        try:
            response = client.describe_db_instances()
            rds_report.append(response)
        except (ClientError, Exception) as e:
            print(e)
    return reportd_rds


def main():
... some arguments definition
    session = get_rds_session(profile_name)
    regions = session.get_available_regions('rds')
    try:
        args = ((session, region, engine_types) for region in regions)
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        reports = executor.map(lambda p: get_rds_instances(*p), args)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

    ... process report

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this code completed in ~3 seconds.

So, my question, is this difference normal, am I missing something for asyncio or doing something wrong for asyncio?

Edit:

[describe_db_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds/client/describe_db_instances.html)

Thanks!

Comment: All depends whats happening in `client.describe_db_instances()` - I suppose this function isn't using Pyhon's async features so the tasks are running sequentially. The second example is using threads so it completes faster.

Comment: If you make a blocking call inside of an async routine, the event loop is blocked and everything waits for it to complete. Assuming client.describe_db_instances blocks, then you really did this all serially in the first case. In the second case, a bunch of threads ran in parallel so it didn't matter if each one blocked.

Comment: In the async world, all blocking calls should be in a separate thread. Its the giant gaping hole in python's async - different models are blended and you just kinda have to know what anything you call does.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, describe_db_instances is a boto3 API' s. I edited the question. So, blocking describe_db_instances function is the bottleneck and to mitigate the issue and make it faster multithreading, concurrent.futures is the only choice.

Comment: Also, @Michal Charemza' s stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348725/boto3-a-future-or-coroutine-is-required), boto3 functions aren' t asyncio-aware. Thanks again, Andrey Kesely and tdelaney.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN There's async version of boto3 - https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/ If you could rewrite the describe_db_instances using this library you could make it faster. Or use multiple threads - as the second example.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN - barring use of the async version, yeah, you need the multithreaded version.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to my colleagues, describe_db_instances is the blockable functions, but creating multiple threads for each region did help like @user4815162342 provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027940/is-run-in-executor-optimized-for-running-in-a-loop-with-coroutines). So here my code changes:

```
def get_session(profile):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
    return session


def get_clients(session):
    regions = session.get_available_regions('rds')
    clients = [session.client('rds', region_name=region) for region in regions]
    return clients


async def get_instances(client, engine_types):
    output = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        response = await loop.run_in_executor(None, client.describe_db_instances)
        output.append(response['DBInstances'])
    except (ClientError, Exception) as e:
        print(e)
    return output


async def main():
... some arguments definition
    session = get_session(profile_name)
    clients = get_clients(session)

    reports = await asyncio.gather(*[get_instances(client, engine) for client in clients])

... process report

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @Andrej Kesely and tdelaney, could you please review it? I want to learn what you think.